# Late-binding public object variable in one sub and losing contents when execution moves to next sub

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I have a form which calls a number of subs from Module1. In Module1 I have a publicly declared object variable. The idea with that variable is to create a late-binded `scripting.dictionary` to avoid having to add too many references to my current vba project. The dictionary is successfully created and populated in Sub1. But, once Sub1 completes and Sub2 is called I notice the dictionary variable has reverted back to its original type of Object.

Login Form:

```
Public progresslbl As Object, subprogresslbl As Object, progressbar As Object, webBr As Object

Private Sub GetExports_Click()
...
...
...
progresslbl.Caption = "Requesting Exports"
RequestExports

'Wait for all emails to be received (reset currentsupplier and count emails, wait for currentsupplier = suppliercount)
WaitforEmails 'Still needs to be created

'Download Exports & Save them to destination user specifies
DownloadFiles


'Restore Outlook: remove temp folder and rule
progresslbl.Caption = "Restoring Outlook Settings"
RestoreOutlook
```

Module1:

```
Public IE As Object, downloadTo As String, Outlook As Object, Items As Object, err As Integer, itemdic As Object
'itemdic shows as type Object in Watch window

Sub RequestExports()

    Set itemdic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"): itemdic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    'itemdic now shows at type scripting.dictionary in Watch window
    For x = 1 To suppliercount
        With IE.Document
            esplogin.subprogresslbl.Caption = "Searching for Supplier " & x & " of " & suppliercount
            currentsupplier = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & x).Value

            delay 3 'Wait 3 seconds to allow screen to load fully

            .getElementById("supplierSearchTextBox").Focus 'Select Search Box
            .getElementById("supplierSearchTextBox").Value = currentsupplier 'Fill in Search Box

            'Invoke keypress event so the contents are detected
            Set evt = .CreateEvent("keyboardevent"): evt.initEvent "change", True, False
            .getElementById("supplierSearchTextBox").dispatchEvent evt

            Dim searchButton As Object: Set searchButton = .getElementsByTagName("a")(5)
            searchButton.Click

            delay 3

            Dim supplierLink As Object: Set supplierLink = .getElementsByTagName("a")(6)
            'Cycle through list of suppliers in excel until we find another active one
            Do While supplierLink Is Nothing
                err = err + 1
                esplogin.subprogresslbl.Caption = "Supplier Not Found"
                delay 1
                ActiveSheet.Range("A" & x).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                If x = suppliercount Then Exit For
                esplogin.progressbar.Width = 150 / suppliercount * x
                x = x + 1
                esplogin.subprogresslbl.Caption = "Searching for Supplier " & x & " of " & suppliercount
                currentsupplier = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & x).Value
                'Select & Fill in Search Box
                .getElementById("supplierSearchTextBox").Focus
                .getElementById("supplierSearchTextBox").Value = currentsupplier

                'Invoke keypress event so the contents are detected
                Set evt = .CreateEvent("keyboardevent"): evt.initEvent "change", True, False
                .getElementById("supplierSearchTextBox").dispatchEvent evt

                Set searchButton = .getElementsByTagName("a")(5)
                searchButton.Click

                delay 2

                Set supplierLink = .getElementsByTagName("a")(6)
            Loop
            'Login to supplier
            supplierLink.Click

            While IE.Busy
                DoEvents
            Wend

            esplogin.subprogresslbl.Caption = "Exporting Supplier " & x & " of " & suppliercount
            delay 4

            Dim exportButton As Object: Set exportButton = .getElementsByTagName("button")(3)
            exportButton.Click

            delay 1
            .getElementsByTagName("select")(0).Value = "all"
            .getElementsByTagName("select")(1).Value = "5"
            delay 1
            .getElementById("btnExport").Click 'Click Export button
            delay 2

            'Click Ok button to close "Export sent to email" window
            Dim exportResultOK As Object: Set exportResultOK = .getElementById("exportProductModalResul").getElementsByTagName("button")(1)
            exportResultOK.Click

            esplogin.subprogresslbl.Caption = "Awaiting Export Confirm. Email for Supplier " & x & " of " & suppliercount
            delay 1

            Set eitDashboardButton = .getElementsByTagName("a")(11)
            eitDashboardButton.Click
        End With

        'Check to see if latestExport confirmation has arrived yet
        Set latestExport = Items.Find("[Subject] = ""Product Updates Product Export confirmation""")
        'If we haven't already found the latestExport wait and keep checking until we do
        Do While latestExport Is Nothing
            Set latestExport = Items.Find("[Subject] = ""Product Updates Product Export confirmation""")
        Loop

        esplogin.subprogresslbl.Caption = "Received Confirm. Email for Supplier " & x & " of " & suppliercount

        With latestExport
            BatchID = Mid(.Body, InStr(1, .Body, "Batch ID of ", vbTextCompare) + 12, InStrRev(.Body, ".", Len(.Body) - 1, vbTextCompare) - (InStr(1, .Body, "Batch ID of ", vbTextCompare) + 12))
            itemdic.Add currentsupplier, BatchID
            latestExport.Subject = "Product Updates Product Export confirmation - " & currentsupplier
            latestExport.Save 'Save the updated subject
        End With

        esplogin.progressbar.Width = 150 / suppliercount * x
    Next x

    esplogin.progresslbl.Caption = "Export Requests Complete"

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    Exit Sub
Restore:
    RestoreOutlook
    MsgBox ("Issue with Export code")
End Sub


Sub WaitforEmails(Optional currentcount As Integer = 0)

////As soon as the code reaches this point the item dic variable is now a type Object again and has no values

    Dim item As Object, BatchID As String, k As Object

    For Each item In Items
        With item
            If .Subject = "Product Updates: Product Export" Then
                'Instr check for batch id (ie dic key) then whatever dic value it matches replace batch id in dic with download link
                For Each k In itemdic.keys
                    If InStr(1, .HTMLBody, k, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        'Store the download link in place of the batch id
                        itemdic(k) = Mid(.HTMLBody, InStr(1, .HTMLBody, "a href=") + 8, (InStrRev(.HTMLBody, ">here") - 2) - (InStr(1, .HTMLBody, "a href=") + 8))
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                currentcount = currentcount + 1
                If currentcount = (suppliercount - errs) Then Exit For 'we have all of the emails
            End If
        End With
    Next
    If Not currentcount = (suppliercount - errs) Then Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "WaitforEmails(currentcount)"
    While Not currentcount = (suppliercount - errs)
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Exit Sub
Restore:
    RestoreOutlook
    MsgBox ("Issue with WaitforEmail code")
End Sub

'When moving to sub 2 itemdic now reverts back to showing as type Object in Watch window

Sub 2()
    'Work with items in dictionary
    'Application or Object-defined Error I believe?
    'Some error
End Sub
```

**My Question:**

Is there a way to have the late-binded dictionary variable keep its type (and its contents/values) across subs (in Module1) without having to add the reference?

Comment: Add `debug.print itemdic.comparemode` as the last executable statement in the first procedure and also as the first executable statement in the second procedure. There are four possible results (success/fail for 2 statements each); which one you get can tell something about where the problem is. It could even be some other code that executes between the calls to the two subroutines.

Comment: I'll have to wait until Monday to debug it since I can't have outlook set up with my work email at home due to network restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, so I feel like a real moron. The issue has been looking me in the face the entire time, well partly at least. I believe the issue was two-pronged:

1. The project needed to be "cleaned" (exported the Module and Form and imported them into a new project)

   - This took care of the `itemdic` not having it's values when arriving to the `WaitforEmails` sub. However, I did notice that when I reach the end of the first sub `itemdic` has the correct type and has values. What I realized is when it goes back to the code of the Userform it shows (temporarily) in the Watch window as having no values and being a type Object again, which is weird, but I imagine it's because the Each window is looking within the scope of whichever current module is actively executing code which makes sense. Once the `WaitforEmails` sub is called from the Userform and the code is going through the lines in that sub `itemdic` shows correctly with values and as type Dictionary.
2. The `key` variable that I use to loop through the items in the dictionary is declared wrong, it should be declared as a `Variant` not an `Object` (doh!)

Answer (score 1):

Something in `Sub1` must be resetting your project.

The following works fine:

```
Public D As Object

Sub sub1()
    Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    D.Add "hello", "world"
End Sub

Sub sub2()
    Debug.Print D("hello")
End Sub

Sub test()
    sub1
    sub2 'prints "world" in the immediate window
End Sub
```

*But* -- the following works differently:

```
Public D As Object

Sub sub1()
    Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    D.Add "hello", "world"
    End
End Sub

Sub sub2()
    Debug.Print D("hello")
End Sub

Sub test()
    sub1
    sub2 'call doesn't print anything
End Sub
```

Make sure that you don't have any stray `End` in your code. If it isn't `End` it is something else. In any event, there is definitely no restriction in VBA about late-binding a public object variable in one sub and using that bound object in another.

Comment: That's good news to hear about there not being such a restriction on public objects. I don't have any `End` calls in Sub1. The only thing I have is the standard `Exit Sub` right before my error-trapping. Could that be causing it? Also, I'm assuming you used `test()` as a UserForm's sub?

Comment: I don't know. I just replaced `End` in my sub with `Exit Sub` and had no problem. I even added an error handler and deliberately triggered it and had no problem. Can you get it to a small enough reproducible problem that can be posted in whole?

Comment: You mentioned error handling -- are any errors actually happening or is that a precaution? Error handling should prevent an error from resetting the project (it did in my quick experiment) but maybe some errors are harder to recover from than others. Maybe there is more of a problem if the error occurs in a userform's code.

Comment: It's just a precaution. I've always been told that it's good coding practice to have something "just in case." I'm certain it isn't an issue with the UserForm's code because the subs execute one after the other almost immediately with just a label being (successfully) updated. That's why I'm so perplexed because I have a late-bound instance of Internet Explorer that's also publicly declared as `Public IE as Object` and that holds everything between subs. I'll be near my computer in a bit to update the code in my question. Right now I'm on my phone.

Comment: That business about the `Public IE` not losing its value but the dictionary losing it seems genuinely puzzling. I can't think of a single reason why some public variables (declared in the same module?) would lose state but others retain it. It could be that your project has become corrupt somehow.

Comment: I've updated my code to include the specific subs for a clearer picture.